# Flink Scala - Extending WindowFunction

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to figure out how to write my own `WindowFunction` but having issues, and I can not figure out why. The issue I am having is with the apply function, as it does not recognize `MyWindowFunction` as a valid input, so I can not compile. The data I am streaming contains `(timestamp,x,y)` where x and y are 0 and 1 for testing. `extractTupleWithoutTs` simply returns a tuple `(x,y)`. I have been running the code with simple sum and reduce functions with success. Grateful for any help :) Using Flink 1.3

Imports:

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.function.WindowFunction
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.watermark.Watermark
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.TimeWindow
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector
```

Rest of the code:

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)
val text = env.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new TsExtractor)
val tuple = text.map( str => extractTupleWithoutTs(str))
val counts = tuple.keyBy(0).timeWindow(Time.seconds(5)).apply(new MyWindowFunction())
counts.print()
env.execute("Window Stream")
```

MyWindow function which is basically copy paste from example with changes of the types.

```
class MyWindowFunction extends WindowFunction[(Int, Int), Int, Int, TimeWindow] {
  def apply(key: Int, window: TimeWindow, input: Iterable[(Int, Int)], out: Collector[Int]): () = {
    var count = 0
    for (in <- input) {
      count = count + 1
    }
    out.collect(count)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the third type parameter of the `WindowFunction`, i.e., the type of the key. The key is declared with an index in the `keyBy` method (`keyBy(0)`). Therefore, the type of the key cannot be determined at compile time. The same problem arises, if you declare the key as a string, i.e., `keyBy("f0")`.

There are two options to resolve this:

1. Use a `KeySelector` function in `keyBy` to extract the key (something like `keyBy(_._1)`). The return type of the `KeySelector` function is known at compile time such that you can use a correctly typed `WindowFunction` with an `Int` key.
2. Change the type of the third type parameter of the `WindowFunction` to `org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple`, i.e., `WindowFunction[(Int, Int), Int, org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple, TimeWindow]`. `Tuple` is a generic holder for the keys extracted by `keyBy`. In your case it will be a `org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple1`. In `WindowFunction.apply()` you can cast `Tuple` to `Tuple1` and access the key field by `Tuple1.f0`.

Comment: Using 1: Using the KeySelector basically solved my problem. Another problem appeared in the class MyWindowFunction afterwards. Instead of () = {..} in the append function, I needed to change to Unit instead of (). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, for your information. I have tried with Tuple1. Does not do any difference.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. What do you mean by "Does not do any difference"? Is it working as well or does the problem persist?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. When using Tuple1, the problem persist. Simply does not work.

Comment: The `WindowFunction` must be defined with `Tuple` as key type (note, this must be Flink's `Tuple` class), i.e., `WindowFunction[(Int, Int), Int, org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple, TimeWindow]`. In the `apply()` method, `Tuple` can be casted to `Tuple1` (again, Flink's Java `Tuple1`, not Scala's built-in `Tuple1`).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I clarified my answer.